# How could skforecast.ForecasterAutoreg predict without lag?

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

I'm using now [skforecast](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiM7fOku5z_AhVLNuwKHcxjCLsQFnoECB0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fskforecast.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw0PPIBTqFLD6ym2Q7ouyMmj) to forecast kind of usual multivariate time series. My training set `trainX`, `trainy` is 36 steps long, and I also have a 12-step-long test set `testX`, `testy` as well. I have trained my regressor with 12 historical steps backward (`lag`) as follows:

```
model = ForecasterAutoreg(regressor=RandomForestRegressor(), lags=12)
model.fit(y=trainX.y, exog=trainX[trainX.columns[1:]])
```

Now, when I give predictions with this trained model on my test features

```
len(testX) # =12
predy = model2.predict(steps=steps, exog=testX[testX.columns[1:]])
len(predy) # =12 as well
```

it gives back 12 predicted steps, so equivalent to the length of the entire `testX`.

I'm confused at this point because my interpretation is that the prediction must be based on some `lag` steps back (12 in my case), which are precursors for the predictions but aren't part of the actual steps-to-predicted. So I do not understand how could my model give forecasts for all my `testX` rows? What is the basis for the prediction for the first value of `predy` for example? Prediction for `predy[0]` should be based on 12 values before `predX[0]`, but no 12 steps back before `predX[0]` evidently.

What do I misunderstand here?

Answer (score 0):

I think because Skforecast assumes your test set starts right after the train set time interval. So it uses the last seen window from the train set as the previous lag values for the first prediction on the test data. Once it makes the first prediction on the test set, it slides the window and uses this predicted value for the next step and so on. Recursive forecasting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).